# Does it make sense to connect different ideas that start with "to" with commas?

Tags: commas

I'm currently writing a statement of purpose and had a question.

What I want to write is something like:

> My past research experience has ranged from creating X, to doing something with Y, and finally to doing Z1 and Z2.

The reason why this sounds a little awkward to me is because normally when I hear the phrase "range from A to B" I think of a starting and ending point without any stops in between. In this particular case, I'd like to include the intermediate information but also give it a sequential feel.

Is the way that I wrote fine, or is there a better (or perhaps correct) way to write it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear whether X, Y and Z1 and Z2 are completely different or are somehow related.  Maybe a more concrete example would help with this.

Comment: Did your experience of 'doing something with Y' end before you began doing the Z activities or did the Y and Z activities overlap?

Comment: Well, Shakey would also use semicolons and colons.  "To die, to sleep; To sleep: perchance to dream", but then he's a little weird.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been a bit clearer. There is no overlap among X, Y, and Z1/2. Those are separate projects that I did, but X is in a different subfield than Y and the Z's. I wanted to say something along the line of my research starting in X but then it progressed towards my main field of interest through Y and Z1/2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be sequential, I would say something like “has gone from creating X to doing something with Y to finally doing Z1 and Z2.” You don’t need commas with a “from... to... to...” format, so if you keep your original sentence you should delete the first comma.